# Why does my entire network lose internet connection for a few seconds when a torrent is started?

Tags: networking, router, bittorrent

Whenever my wife or I start a torrent on her Windows PC (wired), my Windows PC (wired) or my Ubuntu Laptop (wireless), our entire network loses connection for 5-10 seconds.

I have tested this with extremely small and extremely large files and after the 10 seconds or so are over there is no further issue, even if the torrent is still going, or even if it finishes in 1 second. I've tried limiting the max bandwidth on the torrent clients to as low as 500kbps. It does not seem to be a bandwidth issue.

We are using a Netgear R6350 Router connected to an Arris Surfboard SB6183 modem on a 500/50Mbps DOCSIS 3.0 connection with Xfinity/Comcast.

Answer (score 1):

Without lots of testing, I think only speculatiom is possible. I hypothesize as follows -

1. Your torrenting creates a flurry of connections to different IP addresses and the connection tracking in the modem is overwhelmed until this settles down. You may be able to test this by greaty cutting down the.number of simultaneous connections and reducing the amount of content you share.
2. Your torrenting software may be utilising upnp to open up incoming ports on the router which may involve an outage. I guess there will be settings to disable this / assign static ports if that is the case.